# How to deploy "Verily Pathfinder Virtual Agent Template for COVID-19"

Tags: angular, go, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-go

I would like to try "Verily Pathfinder Virtual Agent Template for COVID-19" (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/covid19-rapid-response-demo)

I tried it, but had some difficulties.
Could you help me please?

I use Windows 10, Windows Subsystems for Linux, Debian 10 and
[Google Cloud SDK 296.0.1, alpha 2020.06.10, app-engine-go app-engine-python 1.9.91, app-engine-python-extras 1.9.91, beta 2020.06.10, bq 2.0.57, core 2020.06.10, gsutil 4.51, kubectl 2020.06.10]

I followed github's README.
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/covid19-rapid-response-demo

---

> [Requirements]
>
> A GCP Project with existing Dialogflow Agent setup in a project we'll
> refer to as PROJECTDIALOGFLOW A second GCP project that will host this
> application using AppEngine we'll refer to as PROJECTAPPENGINE You
> must login to gcloud as a user that has access to both projects.
> Install gcloud SDK Install node.js Install make
>
> [Requirements for development]
>
> run npm install -g @angular/cli
>
> [Setup]
>
> In /Makefile set PROJECTDIALOGFLOW and PROJECTAPPENGINE In
> /server/app.yaml Set PROJECTDIALOGFLOW Run make init
>
> [To Develop]
>
> Run export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=[replace with the path to
> this app]/creds/creds.json Run make dev

---

I got through these instructions and had no problem.
However, when I deployed, I got an error message.

---

> [To Deploy]
>
> Run make deploy

---

This is what I got in my terminal.

```
kazu@DESKTOP-IBOI222:~/covid19-rapid-response-demo$ make deploy
gcloud config set project "covid19agent"
Updated property [core/project].
rm -rf server/dist
cd chat-interface && ng build --prod
Your global Angular CLI version (9.1.8) is greater than your local
version (9.0.7). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
Generating ES5 bundles for differential loading...
ES5 bundle generation complete.

chunk {2} polyfills-es2015.de6ca55401f7d78277d5.js (polyfills) 36.1 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {0} runtime-es2015.0811dcefd377500b5b1a.js (runtime) 1.45 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {0} runtime-es5.0811dcefd377500b5b1a.js (runtime) 1.45 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {3} polyfills-es5.82bdfba5af5aad3535ae.js (polyfills-es5) 129 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {1} main-es2015.37720bb28c36281f1d08.js (main) 705 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {1} main-es5.37720bb28c36281f1d08.js (main) 765 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {4} styles.904025a394295e3f0808.css (styles) 170 bytes [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2020-06-15T08:13:44.763Z - Hash: b7cc345f99b4ec3d4fbf - Time: 77431ms
cd server && gcloud app deploy -q
Services to deploy:

descriptor: [/home/kazu/covid19-rapid-response-demo/server/app.yaml]
source: [/home/kazu/covid19-rapid-response-demo/server]
target project: [covid19agent]
target service: [default]
target version: [20200615t171408]
target url: [https://covid19agent.uc.r.appspot.com]


Beginning deployment of service [default]...
Created .gcloudignore file. See `gcloud topic gcloudignore` for details.
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
╠═ Uploading 36 files to Google Cloud Storage ═╣
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
File upload done.
Updating service [default]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build 2d33eb05-376c-4fbb-a67b-470bbf635e22 status: FAILURE
Build error details: {"error":"errorType":"BuildError","canonicalCode":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","errorId":"E93BE526","errorMessage":
"2020/06/15 08:14:40 Building /tmp/staging/srv, with main package at ., saving to /tmp/staging/usr/local/bin/start\n2020/06/15
08:14:40 Running \u0026{/usr/local/go/bin/go [go build -o /tmp/staging/usr/local/bin/start .] [PATH=/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/
builder/google-cloud-sdk/bin/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin HOSTNAME=ad4de922422c HOME=/builder/
home BUILDER_OUTPUT=/builder/outputs DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive GOROOT=/usr/local/go/ GOPATH=/go GO111MODULE=on GOCACHE=/tm
p/cache GOPATH=/go] /tmp/staging/srv \u003cnil\u003e \u003cnil\u003e \u003cnil\u003e [] \u003cnil\u003e \u003cnil\u003e \u003cn
il\u003e \u003cnil\u003e \u003cnil\u003e false [] [] [] [] \u003cnil\u003e \u003cnil\u003e}\n2020/06/15 08:16:01 Wrote build ou
tput to /builder/outputs/output\n2020/06/15 08:16:01 Failed to build app: [go build -o /tmp/staging/usr/local/bin/start .] with
env [PATH=/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/builder/google-cloud-sdk/bin/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bi
n HOSTNAME=ad4de922422c HOME=/builder/home BUILDER_OUTPUT=/builder/outputs DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive GOROOT=/usr/local/go/
GOPATH=/go GO111MODULE=on GOCACHE=/tmp/cache GOPATH=/go] failed: err=exit status 1, out=\"go: finding github.com/golang/protob
uf v1.4.0-rc.4\\ngo: finding google.golang.org/protobuf v1.20.1\\ngo: finding google.golang.org/genproto v0.0.0-20200324203455-
a04cca1dde73\\ngo: finding cloud.google.com/go v0.55.0\\ngo: finding google.golang.org/protobuf v1.20.1-0.20200309200217-e05f78
9c0967\\ngo: finding github.com/google/go-cmp v0.4.0\\ngo: finding golang.org/x/xerrors v0.0.0-20191204190536-9bdfabe68543\\ngo
: finding google.golang.org/genproto v0.0.0-20200317114155-1f3552e48f24\\ngo: finding golang.org/x/lint v0.0.0-20200302205851-7
38671d3881b\\ngo: finding google.golang.org/grpc v1.28.0\\ngo: finding golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20200301022130-244492dfa37a\\ngo
: finding golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20200317113312-5766fd39f98d\\ngo: finding honnef.co/go/tools v0.0.1-2020.1.3\\ngo: finding gi
thub.com/googleapis/gax-go/v2 v2.0.5\\ngo: finding cloud.google.com/go/pubsub v1.2.0\\ngo: finding github.com/BurntSushi/toml v
0.3.1\\ngo: finding github.com/google/pprof v0.0.0-20200229191704-1ebb73c60ed3\\ngo: finding google.golang.org/genproto v0.0.0-
20190819201941-24fa4b261c55\\ngo: finding google.golang.org/api v0.20.0\\ngo: finding cloud.google.com/go/storage v1.6.0\\ngo:
finding github.com/kisielk/gotool v1.0.0\\ngo: finding github.com/ianlancetaylor/demangle v0.0.0-20181102032728-5e5cf60278f6\\n
go: finding github.com/golang/protobuf v1.3.3\\ngo: finding golang.org/x/tools v0.0.0-20200317043434-63da46f3035e\\ngo: finding
github.com/chzyer/readline v0.0.0-20180603132655-2972be24d48e\\ngo: finding golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20200222125558-5a598a2470a
0\\ngo: finding github.com/envoyproxy/protoc-gen-validate v0.1.0\\ngo: finding golang.org/x/tools v0.0.0-20200204074204-1cc6d1e
f6c74\\ngo: finding golang.org/x/sync v0.0.0-20190911185100-cd5d95a43a6e\\ngo: finding golang.org/x/lint v0.0.0-20200130185559-
910be7a94367\\ngo: finding golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20190311183353-d8887717615a\\ngo: finding golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-2019120407
2324-ce4227a45e2e\\ngo: finding go.opencensus.io v0.22.3\\ngo: finding golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20200202164722-d101bd2416d5\\ngo
: finding google.golang.org/genproto v0.0.0-20200204135345-fa8e72b47b90\\ngo: finding github.com/golang/protobuf v1.4.0-rc.2\\n
go: finding github.com/chzyer/test v0.0.0-20180213035817-a1ea475d72b1\\ngo: finding golang.org/x/mod v0.0.0-20190513183733-4bf6
d317e70e\\ngo: finding google.golang.org/genproto v0.0.0-20190425155659-357c62f0e4bb\\ngo: finding golang.org/x/oauth2 v0.0.0-2
0180821212333-d2e6202438be\\ngo: finding cloud.google.com/go v0.52.0\\ngo: finding github.com/chzyer/logex v1.1.10\\ngo: findin
g golang.org/x/text v0.3.0\\ngo: finding github.com/google/pprof v0.0.0-20191218002539-d4f498aebedc\\ngo: finding google.golang
.org/grpc v1.27.1\\ngo: finding golang.org/x/net v0.0
Full build logs: https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds/2d33eb05-376c-4fbb-a67b-470bbf635e22?project=822303710513
make: *** [Makefile:20: deploy] Error 1
```

I accessed this URL(https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds/2d33eb05-376c-4fbb-a67b-470bbf635e22?project=822303710513)
and this is the full build logs.

---

```
starting build "2d33eb05-376c-4fbb-a67b-470bbf635e22"

FETCHSOURCE
BUILD
Starting Step #0 - "fetcher"
Step #0 - "fetcher": Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcs-fetcher
Step #0 - "fetcher": Fetching manifest gs://staging.covid19agent.appspot.com/ae/64dc67bf-1611-4f7f-93cc-df096803bb14/manifest.json.
Step #0 - "fetcher": Processing 37 files.
Step #0 - "fetcher": ******************************************************
Step #0 - "fetcher": Status:                      SUCCESS
Step #0 - "fetcher": Started:                     2020-06-15T08:14:25Z
Step #0 - "fetcher": Completed:                   2020-06-15T08:14:26Z
Step #0 - "fetcher": Requested workers:    200
Step #0 - "fetcher": Actual workers:        37
Step #0 - "fetcher": Total files:           37
Step #0 - "fetcher": Total retries:          0
Step #0 - "fetcher": GCS timeouts:           0
Step #0 - "fetcher": MiB downloaded:         1.70 MiB
Step #0 - "fetcher": MiB/s throughput:       4.48 MiB/s
Step #0 - "fetcher": Time for manifest:    190.17 ms
Step #0 - "fetcher": Total time:             0.57 s
Step #0 - "fetcher": ******************************************************
Finished Step #0 - "fetcher"
Starting Step #1 - "builder"
Step #1 - "builder": Pulling image: gcr.io/gae-runtimes/go112_app_builder:go112_20200531_1_12_17_RC00
Step #1 - "builder": go112_20200531_1_12_17_RC00: Pulling from gae-runtimes/go112_app_builder
Step #1 - "builder": 4be3a941509a: Already exists
Step #1 - "builder": 6dce392178ba: Already exists
Step #1 - "builder": 3c2cba919283: Already exists
Step #1 - "builder": 962a3a0b7284: Already exists
Step #1 - "builder": 2e3a3f41e49d: Already exists
Step #1 - "builder": 83bf9167be41: Already exists
Step #1 - "builder": 5f28d4da3777: Already exists
Step #1 - "builder": 9d496b5b5fbd: Already exists
Step #1 - "builder": 3fc0f2817de9: Already exists
Step #1 - "builder": d0a1ad8b64b4: Already exists
Step #1 - "builder": 47b9ab73f5d7: Already exists
Step #1 - "builder": 8e7e87b95ad4: Pulling fs layer
Step #1 - "builder": fe6f1b585637: Pulling fs layer
Step #1 - "builder": c1da672172b9: Pulling fs layer
Step #1 - "builder": b25fc0831477: Pulling fs layer
Step #1 - "builder": 3147dd420f16: Pulling fs layer
Step #1 - "builder": b25fc0831477: Waiting
Step #1 - "builder": 3147dd420f16: Waiting
Step #1 - "builder": 8e7e87b95ad4: Verifying Checksum
Step #1 - "builder": 8e7e87b95ad4: Download complete
Step #1 - "builder": fe6f1b585637: Verifying Checksum
Step #1 - "builder": fe6f1b585637: Download complete
Step #1 - "builder": b25fc0831477: Verifying Checksum
Step #1 - "builder": b25fc0831477: Download complete
Step #1 - "builder": 3147dd420f16: Verifying Checksum
Step #1 - "builder": 3147dd420f16: Download complete
Step #1 - "builder": 8e7e87b95ad4: Pull complete
Step #1 - "builder": fe6f1b585637: Pull complete
Step #1 - "builder": c1da672172b9: Verifying Checksum
Step #1 - "builder": c1da672172b9: Download complete
Step #1 - "builder": c1da672172b9: Pull complete
Step #1 - "builder": b25fc0831477: Pull complete
Step #1 - "builder": 3147dd420f16: Pull complete
Step #1 - "builder": Digest: sha256:6dd36941797322f65fdbf4444ce9a7db31d5d64fb499a930ab645de28dcfe781
Step #1 - "builder": Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/gae-runtimes/go112_app_builder:go112_20200531_1_12_17_RC00
Step #1 - "builder": gcr.io/gae-runtimes/go112_app_builder:go112_20200531_1_12_17_RC00
Step #1 - "builder": 2020/06/15 08:14:39 Starting commonbuild with args [commonbuild --runtime=go112 --entrypoint= --src=/workspace --config-file=/.googleconfig/app_start.json --main= -- build --name=us.gcr.io/covid19agent/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:64dc67bf-1611-4f7f-93cc-df096803bb14 --directory=/workspace --destination=/srv --additional-directory=/.googleconfig --base=us.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/go112:go112_20200531_1_12_17_RC00 --main=].
Step #1 - "builder": 2020/06/15 08:14:40 No start command generator found for go112, using default app start command "serve".
Step #1 - "builder": 2020/06/15 08:14:40 Writing configuration file "/.googleconfig/app_start.json".
Step #1 - "builder": 2020/06/15 08:14:40 Invoking build command "build --name=us.gcr.io/covid19agent/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:64dc67bf-1611-4f7f-93cc-df096803bb14 --directory=/workspace --destination=/srv --additional-directory=/.googleconfig --base=us.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/go112:go112_20200531_1_12_17_RC00 --main=".
Step #1 - "builder": 2020/06/15 08:14:40 Building /tmp/staging/srv, with main package at ., saving to /tmp/staging/usr/local/bin/start
Step #1 - "builder": 2020/06/15 08:14:40 Running &{/usr/local/go/bin/go [go build -o /tmp/staging/usr/local/bin/start .] [PATH=/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/builder/google-cloud-sdk/bin/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin HOSTNAME=ad4de922422c HOME=/builder/home BUILDER_OUTPUT=/builder/outputs DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive GOROOT=/usr/local/go/ GOPATH=/go GO111MODULE=on GOCACHE=/tmp/cache GOPATH=/go] /tmp/staging/srv <nil> <nil> <nil> [] <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> false [] [] [] [] <nil> <nil>}
Step #1 - "builder": 2020/06/15 08:16:01 Wrote build output to /builder/outputs/output
Step #1 - "builder": 2020/06/15 08:16:01 Failed to build app: [go build -o /tmp/staging/usr/local/bin/start .] with env [PATH=/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/builder/google-cloud-sdk/bin/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin HOSTNAME=ad4de922422c HOME=/builder/home BUILDER_OUTPUT=/builder/outputs DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive GOROOT=/usr/local/go/ GOPATH=/go GO111MODULE=on GOCACHE=/tmp/cache GOPATH=/go] failed: err=exit status 1, out="go: finding github.com/

I omitted here.

finding github.com/stretchr/objx v0.1.0\ngo: finding golang.org/x/tools v0.0.0-20190816200558-6889da9d5479\ngo: finding github.com/davecgh/go-spew v1.1.0\ngo: finding golang.org/x/crypto v0.0.0-20190605123033-f99c8df09eb5\ngo: finding github.com/kr/text v0.1.0\ngo: finding github.com/envoyproxy/go-control-plane v0.9.0\ngo: finding github.com/kr/pty v1.1.1\ngo: finding gopkg.in/yaml.v2 v2.2.2\ngo: finding gopkg.in/check.v1 v1.0.0-20180628173108-788fd7840127\ngo: finding gopkg.in/check.v1 v0.0.0-20161208181325-20d25e280405\ngo: dmitri.shuralyov.com/gpu/mtl@v0.0.0-20190408044501-666a987793e9: unrecognized import path \"dmitri.shuralyov.com/gpu/mtl\" (https fetch: Get https://dmitri.shuralyov.com/gpu/mtl?go-get=1: dial tcp 172.93.50.41:443: i/o timeout)\ngo: error loading module requirements\n"
Step #1 - "builder": 2020/06/15 08:16:01 2020/06/15 08:14:40 Building /tmp/staging/srv, with main package at ., saving to /tmp/staging/usr/local/bin/start
Step #1 - "builder": 2020/06/15 08:14:40 Running &{/usr/local/go/bin/go [go build -o /tmp/staging/usr/local/bin/start .] [PATH=/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/builder/google-cloud-sdk/bin/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin HOSTNAME=ad4de922422c HOME=/builder/home BUILDER_OUTPUT=/builder/outputs DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive GOROOT=/usr/local/go/ GOPATH=/go GO111MODULE=on GOCACHE=/tmp/cache GOPATH=/go] /tmp/staging/srv <nil> <nil> <nil> [] <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> false [] [] [] [] <nil> <nil>}
Step #1 - "builder": 2020/06/15 08:16:01 Wrote build output to /builder/outputs/output
Step #1 - "builder": 2020/06/15 08:16:01 Failed to build app: [go build -o /tmp/staging/usr/local/bin/start .] with env [PATH=/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/builder/google-cloud-sdk/bin/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin HOSTNAME=ad4de922422c HOME=/builder/home BUILDER_OUTPUT=/builder/outputs DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive GOROOT=/usr/local/go/ GOPATH=/go GO111MODULE=on GOCACHE=/tmp/cache GOPATH=/go] failed: err=exit status 1, out="go: finding github.com/golang/protobuf v1.4.0-rc.4\ngo: finding google.golang.org/protobuf v1.20.1\ngo: finding google.golang.org/genproto v0.0.0-20200324203455-a04cca1dde73\ngo: finding cloud.google.com/go v0.55.0\ngo: finding google.golang.org/protobuf v1.20.1-0.20200309200217-e05f789c0967\ngo: finding github.com/google/go-cmp v0.4.0\ngo: finding golang.org/x/xerrors v0.0.0-20191204190536-9bdfabe68543\ngo: finding google.golang.org/genproto v0.0.0-20200317114155-1f3552e48f24\ngo: finding golang.org/x/lint v0.0.0-20200302205851-738671d3881b\ngo: finding google.golang.org/grpc v1.28.0\ngo: finding golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20200301022130-244492dfa37a\ngo: finding golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20200317113312-5766fd39f98d\ngo: finding honnef.co/go/tools v0.0.1-2020.1.3\ngo: finding github.com/googleapis/gax-go/v2 v2.0.5\ngo: finding cloud.google.com/go/

I omitted here.

finding golang.org/x/mobile v0.0.0-20190312151609-d3739f865fa6\ngo: finding golang.org/x/exp v0.0.0-20190829153037-c13cbed26979\ngo: finding google.golang.org/grpc v1.25.1\ngo: finding github.com/kr/pretty v0.1.0\ngo: finding github.com/pmezard/go-difflib v1.0.0\ngo: finding golang.org/x/tools v0.0.0-20191119224855-298f0cb1881e\ngo: finding github.com/stretchr/objx v0.1.0\ngo: finding golang.org/x/tools v0.0.0-20190816200558-6889da9d5479\ngo: finding github.com/davecgh/go-spew v1.1.0\ngo: finding golang.org/x/crypto v0.0.0-20190605123033-f99c8df09eb5\ngo: finding github.com/kr/text v0.1.0\ngo: finding github.com/envoyproxy/go-control-plane v0.9.0\ngo: finding github.com/kr/pty v1.1.1\ngo: finding gopkg.in/yaml.v2 v2.2.2\ngo: finding gopkg.in/check.v1 v1.0.0-20180628173108-788fd7840127\ngo: finding gopkg.in/check.v1 v0.0.0-20161208181325-20d25e280405\ngo: dmitri.shuralyov.com/gpu/mtl@v0.0.0-20190408044501-666a987793e9: unrecognized import path \"dmitri.shuralyov.com/gpu/mtl\" (https fetch: Get https://dmitri.shuralyov.com/gpu/mtl?go-get=1: dial tcp 172.93.50.41:443: i/o timeout)\ngo: error loading module requirements\n"
Finished Step #1 - "builder"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/gae-runtimes/go112_app_builder:go112_20200531_1_12_17_RC00" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message on the logs you share is quite clear:

```
unrecognized import path \"dmitri.shuralyov.com/gpu/mtl\" (https fetch: Get https://dmitri.shuralyov.com/gpu/mtl?go-get=1: dial tcp 172.93.50.41:443: i/o timeout)\ngo: error loading module requirements\n"
```

So, something is blocking the import of that library and making it timeout, the most likely reason is that their is some kind of firewall blocking it, specially since all the google, github, and go related libraries appeared to have been found on the log you shared, you can check more details in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/creating-firewalls), so I suggest you go through the firewall rules of your app engine setup and double check if there is no rule that could be blocking it.

One more thing you could try to do is import this package locally by dowloading the lib and placing it in your local repository and importing it from there.

Other than that, you could contact the creator of the template to check if he does not have a more detailed solutions for that issue on his github repo.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I checked the firewall rules in the cloud console. There is only a default rule and this rule allow all IP adress. Next, I found this modules source code at https://gotools.org/dmitri.shuralyov.com/gpu/mtl . I searched "dmitri.shuralyov.com/gpu/mtl" in my local project directory, and found `dmitri.shuralyov.com/gpu/mtl v0.0.0-20190408044501-666a987793e9/go.mod h1:H6x//7gZCb22OMCxBHrMx7a5I7Hp++hsVxbQ4BYO7hU=` this line in `go.sum` file. Unfortunately, I couldn't find the way to put the lib in a proper place and import it form there.

Comment: 20 days ago, I sent a mail to Covid19Pathfinder Team @Verily (covid19pathfinder@verily.com). They replied "The Google Cloud Platform (GCP) support team can best assist you with this issue. I will notify the GCP support team to look out for your case." And I have never received an ansewer yet. So, I posted this question here.

Comment: I guess you could open a bug report for google cloud platform by yourself in that case, you can use this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187191&template=0) to do it, honestly I think that this is best route to solving this issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. I even didn't know https://issuetracker.google.com/ . I will report a bug.

Comment: I posted on issuetracker. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/161154006 Thank you for your help.